# Storage Spaces M2 SSD recommendations

Tags: dell-poweredge, storage-spaces

i am looking use storage spaces and SSD for my DELL R730, i have a PCIe to SSD adapter (and cannot use RAID controller as all bays are full).

My question relates to the SSDs themselves, i know RAID-5 NAS drives etc had issues dropping drives if non-RAID/NAS firmware on the drive... does the same apply to a drive mirror using commercial SSD?

If not commercial, any recommendations for a database grade M2 SSD that i can pair, as this will be used for a database.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As long as you use Enterprise grade SSDs, ones coming with either battery or capacitor power loss protection you’ll be fine. Physical form factor and attachment type are irrelevant.

https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/storage-at-microsoft/don-t-do-it-consumer-grade-solid-state-drives-ssd-in-storage/ba-p/425914